# itext-7 tutorial for development using asp.net c#

Tags: itext, itext7, electronic-signature

Friends can anyone direct me to any tutorials for itext 7. I am trying to manipulate PDF using itext 7, i have been through there tutorials but they are available for JAVA i need some tutorials in C#. The actual propose is to find equivalent class for the java class that have being used in example in tutorials

Comment: These tutorials are in the works. Please be patient! Also: this question is off-topic. (1.) Any developer who can read the Java code, should be able to produce the C# code. (2.) If you have a *specific* problem with porting a *specific* Java example to C#, you should create a question about that *specific* example and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie for the clarification about the tutorials my actual need is to find equivalent class in c# for existing code such as pdfcanvas.

Comment: @RahulAhire, This might sound like a surprise, but the equivalent of `PdfCanvas` in C# is `PdfCanvas`! It is in namespace `iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas`

Comment: (3.) Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm also looking for examples using iText7. Hows the work going? Maybe You could share part of tutorials/examples that are already done.

Comment: @Misiu The writing process is slow because I have plenty of other work. I hope to finish the [iText 7: building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorial by the end of August. I already have examples for two more chapters [here](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/tree/develop/publications/highlevel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/highlevel). But all depends on how much other work gets on my plate.

Comment: Finding the equivalent classes in C# shouldn't be a problem because iText 7 for Java and iText 7 for C# are more in sync than iText 5 and iTextSharp 5 were. Nevertheless @chrishaas is working on a C# port of the examples.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thank You so much for reply. I understand that writing process is slowly, I admire Your work and I can wait month or so :) I'm not that good as Java to port code between it and C#, so even basic example or documentation of C# classes would help me getting started

Comment: The problem starts when working with images and barcodes.  .NET does not all construction of Image, this is an abstract class.  Please help